# Auto synch Mendeley desktop

Tags: mendeley

Is it possible to automatically synchronize Mendeley desktop every time a new reference is added?
Every time I add a new reference using the web plugin, I have to sync again the desktop version, so that the new reference is recognized and can be cited in Word. Is it possible to automate the process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the new [Mendeley Reference Manager](https://www.mendeley.com/reference-management/reference-manager/), which auto syncs to the cloud.

Also the new [Cite add-in for Word](https://www.mendeley.com/reference-management/mendeley-cite) is a separate install and uses the cloud library directly, so you can skip the Reference Manager altogether and just use it with the Mendeley Web Importer if you prefer that workflow.

Comment: Can I seamlessly use Mendeley Desktop and the Mendeley Reference Manager? I have some PDF in the Desktop version they do not appear in the Mendeley Reference Manager. I am not sure if adding all of them in the desktop will create duplicates.

Comment: You'll just need to sync Mendeley Desktop to the cloud, and then Mendeley Reference Manager should show all your references and collections exactly the same.  Support FAQ about it [here](https://service.elsevier.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/28828/supporthub/mendeley/p/16088/).

Comment: The problem is that Mendeley Desktop is not automatically sync to cloud. It's manual for every new entry. Mendeley Cite word plugin and Mendeley reference manager are. "Mendeley Cite cannot yet be used with citations created with the Mendeley Desktop MS Word plugin. Don’t worry, you can still use the Mendeley Desktop MS Word plugin to edit your citations in this document."

Comment: For now you're right, but the team is working to fix that as soon as we can. You could use Mendeley Cite with a fresh Word document of course, but I guess redoing the citations manually yourself of an existing document using Mendeley Cite might be tedious.